# Replacing parts of a matrix with lists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I want to use lists to easily replace parts of a matrix. As an example, I want to replace the code

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1} -> 13, {1, 2} -> 14}]
```

by something like

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> {13, 14}]
```

which doesn't work. For a general matrix `m`, I want to, given a list of indices of the type `(x,y)`, `li` and a list of replacement values, `lr`, use something like

```
ReplacePart[m, li -> lr}]
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ReplacePart[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, Thread[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> {13, 14}]]
```

so

```
ReplacePart[m, Thread[li -> lr]]
```

in general.

But a `CompiledFunction` will probably do the job quicker because `Thread[li -> lr]` unpacks arrays. Let's see.

```
cReplacePart = 
  Compile[{{A0, _Real, 2}, {pos, _Integer, 2}, {val, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{A = A0},
    If[
      1 <= Max[pos[[All, 1]]] <= Dimensions[A0][[1]] && 
      1 <= Max[pos[[All, 2]]] <= Dimensions[A0][[2]],
     Do[
      A[[Compile`GetElement[pos, i, 1], 
        Compile`GetElement[pos, i, 2]]] = Compile`GetElement[val, i],
      {i, 1, Min[Length[pos], Length[val]]}
      ]
     ];
    A
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

And indeed, it's 100 times as fast:

```
n = 1000;
m = 1000000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
li = RandomInteger[{1, n}, {m, 2}];
lr = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, m];

B = ReplacePart[A, Thread[li -> lr]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
cB = cReplacePart[A, li, lr]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[B - cB]]
```

> 4.91402
>
> 0.047307
>
> 0.

One may also use `SparseArray`; this is only a tiny bit slower than the compiled approach:

```
spB = A SparseArray[li -> 0., Dimensions[A], 1.] + 
     SparseArray[Reverse@li -> Reverse@lr, Dimensions[A], 0.]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
Max[Abs[B - spB]]
```

> 0.086657
>
> 0.

Answer (score 5):

`ReplacePart` has a undocumented four variables form that permits this :

```
oldValuesList = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}
newValuesList = {13, 14}
modifiedPositionsList = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}
newValuesPositions = (* gives the origin of the new data *)
 List /@ Range[Length[newValuesList]] (* simply {{1},{2}} *)

ReplacePart[oldValuesList
 , newValuesList
 , modifiedPositionsList
 , newValuesPositions]
```

> {{13, 14}, {0, 1}}

I have retrieved this information in Michael Trott' s book "Mathematica Guidebook for Programming" page 628.

According to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/5467) It was documented until Version 5.2.

**EDIT**

`ReplacePart` is known to be often not memory/speed optimal. It may be slow and memory consuming with large data sets.

Henrik Schumacher's comments below confirm this in this particular case.

Comment: I would have done `newValuesPositions = Transpose[{Range[Length[newValuesList]]}]` myself.

Comment: I would do `Partition[Range[Length[newValuesList]], 1]`.

Comment: Beware, this applies the changes in reverse order! And it's even slower than `Thread`...

Comment: It's really awfully slow, like several minutes(!) for 1000000 replacements in a 1000 by 1000 matrix (which can actually be done in 0.05 seconds). So I really do not recommend to use the for-argument version for larger data. This is so unfortunate because I really miss this functionality. One may use `SparseArray`, but it is not as well-suited for dense matrices.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
b = {13, 14};
```

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[b &, a, First@Position[a, #] & /@ a[[1]]]

(*{{13, 14}, {0, 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};

b = {13, 14};
```

I suggest `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) or `MapAt`

```
ReplaceAt[a, _ :> b, 1]
```

{{13, 14}, {0, 1}}

```
MapAt[b &, 1] @ a
```

{{13, 14}, {0, 1}}